# Why Unscented Transform does not need Bessel's correction?

Tags: statistics, kalman-filter

The unscented transform evaluates the sample mean and covariance like this:
$$\overline{y}=\sum_{i=0}^{2N}{w_iy_i}$$
$$\Sigma_y=\sum_{i=0}^{2N}{w_i(y_i-\overline{y})(y_i-\overline{y})^T}$$

In statistics, the sample mean and covariance is calculated using the following formulas:
$$\overline{y}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{y_i}$$
$$\Sigma_y=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{(y_i-\overline{y})(y_i-\overline{y})^T}$$

Note that there is a different normalizing factor for the mean and the variance, as the factor for estimating the variance is corrected by $\frac{N}{N-1}$.
However, the factors which are included in $w_i$ are the same for mean and covariance for unscented transform. Why is this the case? Behave the unscented samples like the full population instead of like samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unscented samples, or sigma points, do behave as the full population. The sigma points are deterministically drawn from a Gaussian distribution, and they are meant to fully capture both its mean and covariance. If we have an $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{x}) = \mathcal{N} (\mathbf{x} ; \, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}),
\end{align}
with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and covariance $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$, then we draw the following set of $2n+1$ sigma points from this distribution:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{X}_{0} &= \boldsymbol{\mu}, \\
\mathcal{X}_{i} &= \boldsymbol{\mu} + \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i} & \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, n \\
\mathcal{X}_{i} &= \boldsymbol{\mu} - \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i-n} & \text{for } i = n+1, 2, \dots, 2n. \\
\end{align}
These sigma points are symmetrically distributed on and around the Gaussian's mean.
Here $\lambda = \alpha^{2} (n + \kappa) - n$, where $\alpha$ and $\kappa$ are scaling parameters.
The vector $( \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} )_{i}$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of the $n \times n$ square root matrix $\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}$, where we have
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}^{T} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} )_{i} ( \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} )_{i}^{T}. 
\end{align}
Each sigma point is associated with a weight:
\begin{align}
w_{0} &= \frac{\lambda}{n + \lambda}, \\
w_{i} &= \frac{1}{2 (n + \lambda)} \text{ for } i > 0,
\end{align}
so that $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} w_{i} = 1$.
The sigma points capture the Gaussian's exact mean:
\begin{align}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\mu}} &= \sum_{i=0}^{2n} w_{i} \mathcal{X}_{i} \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{n + \lambda} \boldsymbol{\mu} + \frac{1}{2(n + \lambda)} \Bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big( \boldsymbol{\mu} + \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i} \Big) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big( \boldsymbol{\mu} - \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i} \Big)  \Bigg] \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{n + \lambda} \boldsymbol{\mu} + \frac{1}{2(n + \lambda)} \Bigg[ 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \boldsymbol{\mu} \Bigg] \\
&= \boldsymbol{\mu}.
\end{align}
More importantly to your question, the sigma points capture the Gaussian's exact covariance:
\begin{align}
\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} &= \sum_{i=0}^{2n} w_{i} \big( \mathcal{X}_{i} - \boldsymbol{\mu} \big) \big( \mathcal{X}_{i} - \boldsymbol{\mu} \big)^{T} \\
&= \frac{1}{n + \lambda} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big[ \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i} \Big] \Big[ \Big(  \sqrt{ (n + \lambda) \boldsymbol{\Sigma} }  \Big)_{i} \Big]^{T} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} ( \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} )_{i} ( \sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}} )_{i}^{T} \\
&= \boldsymbol{\Sigma}.
\end{align}
I believe I chose weights that matched your question, but there are other (better) methods of choosing weights.